# login manual in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I try to login without using php artisan make:auth.. I dont know why my select statement show login fail although i enter correct. I hope anyone can help me. Below i attach the code. Thanks in advance

```
public function shw(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $checkLogin = DB::table('admin')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->get();
        if($checkLogin === true)
        {
            echo "Login Successfull";
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        return "fail";
    }

    /**
```

Comment: Is password hashed in database?

Comment: Please NEVER store unhashed passwords

Comment: this is in no way shape or form a manual login, you are just checking if the user with the given email and password exists in your DB.

Use `bcrypt($password)` if you at least store a hashed password in your DB.
But I would recommend that you don't do this manually as it requires a lot to handle yourself.

Comment: this the testing one thats y i use unhashed password

Comment: remove the check `$checkLogin === true` and just use `if ($checkLogin)` the object will contain your user, so it won't be of type boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if password is not hashed then just change these lines

```
public function shw(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    $checkLogin = DB::table('admin')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->first();
    if(!is_null($checkLogin))
    {
        echo "Login Successfull";
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
    return "fail";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really advise you to use the Auth functions in Laravel. This one is already build with the security that you need. (Why do you want to use your own?)

By default the password hashes are stored in the database, not the plain text password. You should use the build-in Auth facade

Like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// Get the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
$id = Auth::id();
```

When $user or $id are empty, you can assume that the user is not logged in.

You can check it with this example

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

But I always prefer to use the middleware auth on your routes

```
Route::put('post/{id}', function ($id) {
    //
})->middleware('auth');
```

Maybe [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication) will help you.

Comment: as you can see he is not using `Auth` so this won't work.

Comment: @nakov Thanks, editted my answer to meet the question requirements

Comment: i am already using auth for my user login..this login is only for admin..that s y i do in normal method...thank for the answers guys

Comment: You can also create a column in the table `users` as a `tinyint` named admin, when this is set to `1` the user can use an admin panel and when it is set to `0` the user will be redirected to another page. (That is my favorite approach)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the **admin** table. There is no admin table created by:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

The table that is responsible for users is **users** table. So try this one:

```
DB::table('users')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->get();
```

Comment: use this to know whats the error: 
`try{
            $checkLogin = DB::table('users')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->get();
            dd($checkLogin);
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            var_dump($e);
        };`

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
$user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
    if ($user && $user->active && \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
// do something
}
```